# Orderby price issue in a WP_Query for Woocommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, price, product-variations

I'm trying to sort my products by price but it doesn't work fine, it returns only 9 of my 56 products.  All my products are similars, all are products with variations and attributes, so I don't know why it happends.

This is my code to get products, it works fine if I don't use the "orderby".

```
$args = [
"posts_per_page" => 20,
"paged"=> "1",
"tax_query" => [
    [
        "taxonomy" => "product_cat",
        "field" => "term_id",
        "terms" => "213",
        "operator" => "IN",
        "include_children" => false
    ],
    [
        "taxonomy" => "pa_color",
        "field" => "term_id",
        "terms" => [
            "red"
        ],
        "operator" => "IN"
    ],
    "relation" => "AND"
],
"post_type" => [
    "product",
    "product_variation"
],
"meta_query" => [
    [
        "key" => "_price",
        "value" => [
            "20",
            "30"
        ],
        "compare" => "BETWEEN",
        "type" => "NUMERIC"
    ],
    "relation" => "AND"
],
"orderby" => "meta_value_num",
"meta_key" => "_price",
"order" => "ASC"
]

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Regarding product variations:**

- Woocommerce custom taxonomies as **product categories** or **product tags** are **not enabled in product variations**, but in their **parent variable product**.
- **Product attributes** *(for variations)* are not available through a tax query. For product variation they are **set as meta data** like `attribute_pa_color`
  *(all keys starting by `attribute_`)* and the value is a term slug for each one

So you can't make your query work for both post types `product` and `product_variation`.

**Note:** Product variations **are not displayed by default in product loops**. They are only displayed in cart items and order items

**2) Regarding Variable products:**

- Regarding prices for a variable product  *(since WooCommerce 3+)*, their will be as many prices (meta key `_prices`) as there is variations in it. So querying meta key `_prices` can make errors, as the first available price will be taken *(or may be all of them or none)*.
- Regarding product attributes it's not so simple as there is 2 kinds:

  - Normal product attributes (like for simple products)
  - Product attributes enabled for variations.

**Note:** Variable products are displayed by default in product loops, **but they are never displayed in cart items and order items**.

> For all that reasons **your query will not work properly anyways** even with or without `"orderby" => "meta_value_num",`.

There is also some errors or mistakes in your query like:

- In your **`tax_query`** for `"taxonomy" => "pa_color",`
  **the `"field"` need to be `"slug"` instead of `"term_id"`**.
- `'post_status' => 'publish',` is missing.
- `"operator" => "IN"`, `"relation" => "AND"` are not needed as they are default arguments.

> So this doesn't solve your question, but show you that is not possible to do it on this way.